# MySQL Unique Session for Running Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

If I have a stored procedure that creates temporary table X everytime it is run, is there a way to run a stored procedure with some sort of unique session ID, so that when person A runs the stored procedure, and it creates temporary table X, then when person B runs the same procedure, it won't create temporary table X as well and then crash.

I basically want to have a procedure that does something, but I want muluple people to run the same procedure at the same time, with out the procedure failing over because temporary tables have already been created.  Just wondering if there is something I could do with session variables in MySQL, or perhaps use someone's connection info to make a session unique to each person running the procedure.  Maybe have table X_session_ID created each time.  Is there a way to generate a unique id within a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the required temporary table using [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) which will prevent name collisions between users without resorting to generating unique identifiers;

> Temporary Tables
>
> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. **A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed.** This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name.

Comment: Thanks. I do use the following CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE search_columns_temp1 as part of my procedure. So everytime the procedure runs, it creates this temp table. Does that mean then that when person A connects, runs the procedure, and person B connects and runs the same procedure at the same time possibly, that two search_columns_temp1 tables are created on the one database?

Comment: @user1236443 Yes, but neither user can see the other user's temporary table, both can have a table with the same name and only see their own.

Comment: I think the problem I have is that the stored procedure has specific priviledges, has been defined by me, and tends to run as me (i.e. SQL SECURITY DEFINER). So everytime this procedure runs, it is run under my details. This was done so that I didn;t have to give lots of users the same privilegse just to run this one procedure. Does the temp table still work?  Is based on connection? or if it is run under me all the time, will it fail because temp table is already created?

Comment: The temporary table is per-connection and not per-user. As long as the calls to the procedure are from a different connection, I cannot see a problem. If you need to call it multiple times in sequence from a single connection, you'll need to drop the temporary table at the end of your procedure since it's only done automatically at disconnect.